# Shipping Postgres inside a node server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, next.js, electron

is there a way to ship a Postgres DB server inside a node server locally? I am building an electron app with Next js inside it. At the moment, the electron app serves the next app inside it, but I dont have a local db. And I am trying to see if I can also build a local postgres database server inside it.

I know I can use SQLite, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: That is not a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: What's the reason you'd prefer not to use SQLite?

Comment: In practical terms, the answer is "no".  Postgres is large, expects to run 24/7, and needs to create a separate username.  It is not designed to be a "local" database.